# How to assign serial no in WordPress Post summary Page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to assign `serial no` in my WordPress Post Category summary Page. For this I have written following code. It is working fine but problem is in the case of paging.

When I am going to 2nd page or 3rd page it assigns the no from 1 again. Currently I am showing 5 posts/per page. Then in 2nd page it should show post no starting from 6 but it starts from 1 again. Same to 3rd and other pages. How can I show it in 1st page from 1-5 and in 2nd page 6-10 etc?

Below is my code:

```
     <?php 
           // args
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;               
            $args = array(
                        'paged'         => $paged, 
                        'post_type'     => 'post',
                        'cat'           => 5,
             ); 
             $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
             $postNumber = 1;// to give serial no to post

    ?>
          <?php if($the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

               <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                 <?php echo $postNumber++; ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
                 <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
               <?php endwhile; ?>

               <?php custom_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>

         <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking help from this topic https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155903/show-number-of-posts-and-number-on-current-page I have been able to solve my problem. Below is my working code:

```
 <?php 
       // args
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
        $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
        $end = $ppp * $paged;              
        $args = array(
                    'paged'         => $paged, 
                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                    'cat'           => 5,
         ); 
         $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
         $postNumber = $end - $ppp + 1;// to give serial no to post

?>
```